# For a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb(R)$, prove that there exists a $x_0$ so that $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0, x_0 \in [a,b]$

Tags: solution-verification

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is n-times differentiable. Let $x_1,...,x_{n+1} \in [a,b]$ with $x_1<...<x_{n+1}$ and $f(x_i)=0$ for all $1\leq i \leq n+1$.

**Prove** that there exists a $x_0 \in (a,b)$ for which $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ is.

Here's what I've came up with so far:

We are finished if $f(x)= \hat{0}$. Therefore, let $f(x) \neq \hat{0}$.
Because $f(x_i)=0$, $i \in \{1,...,n+1\}$, there exists a $U_{\delta}(x_i)$, for which all $x_j\in U_{\delta}(x_i)$, $j \in [a,b]$ and $j\neq i$ are either $j>0$ or $j<0$.

Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$.

Then: $f(x_0) \geq 0$ or $f(x_0) \leq 0$.

If $x_i$ are the local Maxima or Minima and $f^{(1)}(x_i)=...=f^{(n)}(x_i)=0$, we make $f^{(n+1)}(x_i)$ and check for the criteria of local Maxima and Minima and put $x_0 = x_i$.

Are $x_i$ no local extrema, then $x_0$ has to be between the zeros of $f(x)$ and there exists a $x_0$ which $f^{(1)}(x_0)=...=f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$.

**Now** , I know this prove has lots of potential for improvement, but I would like some feedback as I am quite new to Proves and want to improve.

Comment: I think it is more straightforward to apply the mean value theorem to pairs of adjacent zeros, giving $n$ distinct points where $f'(x)$ is 0. Then we can apply the MVT again to pairs of adjacent zeros of $f'$, and so on, until we get to $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. That would apply better than my approach I guess, thanks!

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi, how would one prove that after using the MVT there are still adjacent zeros to keep using for the MVT?

Comment: For each $1\leq k\leq n$, the mean value theorem gives some $x'_k\in (x_k,x_{k+1})$ such that $f'(x'_k)=0$. Since the intervals $(x_k, x_{k+1})$ are all disjoint and $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{n+1}$, this means $x'_1 < x'_2 < \dots < x'_n$, so we're essentially back where we started, just with one less zero and with $f'$ in place of $f$.

Comment: Thank you, I think i got it